# Compress directories older than 7 days

Tags: bash, scripts, tar, archive

I have directories(have some .txt files) like this. I'd like compress the dirs older than 7 days (by changed date) to it's corresponding YYYY_MM dir

2019_08_05_132134_ABC

2019_08_02_084423_ABC

2019_07_30_024651_ABC

2019_07_27_084423_ABC

2019_07_24_084423_ABC

2019_06_15_024651_ABC

2019_06_08_084423_ABC

2019_05_13_084423_ABC

2019_05_07_084423_ABC

If i run the script today, the dirs should move to YYYY_MM.tar.gz file

2019_07_27_084423_ABC, 2019_07_24_084423_ABC - > 2019_07.tar.gz

2019_06_15_024651_ABC, 2019_06_08_084423_ABC - > 2019_06.tar.gz

2019_05_13_084423_ABC, 2019_05_07_084423_ABC - > 2019_05.tar.gz

I have this script so far. I'm looping through Root dir, extract year and month from folder name and creating YYYY_MM dir in TEMP_DIR and move the folder to TEMP_DIR. Next, loop through TEMP_DIR and compress each YYYY_MM folder to .tar.gz and remove the folder YYYY_MM from TEMP_DIR

```
cd $ROOT_DIR
if find $ROOT_DIR -mindepth 1 | read; then
for f in *;do
  year=${f:0:4}
  month=${f:5:2}
 mkdir -p "$TEMP_DIR/${year}_${month}"
 mv -v "$f" "$TEMP_DIR/${year}_${month}/$f"
done

cd $TEMP_DIR
for i in *;do
 tar czf $ARCH_DIR/$i.tar.gz $i
 rm -r $TEMP_DIR/$i
done
```

but it's archiving all the directories, not sure how to restrict to look only 7 days old dirs. I'm new to Linux script, there must be easy way to do this. Hope someone can provide your help on this.

Comment: The `find` command will do exactly what you need. Look at the -mtime option.